# Pytorch : Neural network is not learning at all

Tags: neural-network, pytorch

I'm new to deep learning so I might just miss something stupid.

I'm training several neural networks on trees. I'm trying to generate trees with my neural networks, and I have a reward function to select the best trees after each generation. I try to learn on the 100 best trees, but when I try to learn, my loss is computed correctly but it's constant even after several `optimizer.step()`. I honestly have no idea why it's not working. I'm using `torch.nn.CrossEntorpyLoss` and `torch.optim.SGD`. Here's my entire code but I think the problem is in the `learn` function.
I can give further explanation if necessary.

```
import torch
import random as rd
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import heapq
from time import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 19 # Taille de l'arbre
n_edg = 171 # Taille des vecteurs
iters = 10000 # Nombre d'itérations
bests = 100 # Nombre de graphes sur lesquels on apprend
const = 1 + (n - 1) ** 0.5 # Constante du problème

def create_net(in_size, out_size):
    l1 = torch.nn.Linear(in_size, 64)
    r1 = torch.nn.ReLU()
    l2 = torch.nn.Linear(64, 8)
    r2 = torch.nn.ReLU()
    l3 = torch.nn.Linear(8, out_size)
    s = torch.nn.Softmax(0)
    return torch.nn.Sequential(l1, r1, l2, r2, l3, s)

net_list = [create_net(i * (i - 1) // 2, i) for i in range(2, n)]

def from_edge_vec(g):
    G = nx.Graph()
    G.add_nodes_from(range(n))
    G.add_edge(0, 1)
    index = 0
    for i in range(n - 1):
        for j in range(i + 1):
            if g[index]: G.add_edge(i + 1, j)
            index += 1
    return G

def reward(g, G):
    return g, np.max(nx.adjacency_spectrum(G)) + len(nx.max_weight_matching(G)) - const

def sortSecond(elt):
    return elt[1]

def meanSecond(list):
    acc = 0
    for _, r in list:
        acc += r
    return acc / len(list)

def step():
    v = torch.zeros(iters, n_edg)
    v[:, 0] = 1
    max_index = 1
    for i in range(n - 2):
        out = net_list[i](v[:, :max_index])
        val = torch.multinomial(out, 1)
        for j in range(iters):
            v[j, max_index + val[j]] = 1
        max_index += i + 2
    l = map(from_edge_vec, v)
    acc = map(reward, v, l)
    learn_graphs = heapq.nsmallest(bests, acc, key = sortSecond)
    return learn_graphs

def learn(graph_list):
    criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    prog_v = torch.zeros(bests, n_edg)
    prog_v[:, 0] = 1
    max_index = 1
    for i in range(n - 2):
        net = net_list[i]
        optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=1e-2)
        label = torch.empty(bests, dtype = torch.long)
        for j in range(bests):
            label[j] = torch.argmax(graph_list[j][0][max_index:max_index + i + 2])
        loss = 1
        # while loss > 0.1:
        for _ in range(5):
            out = net(prog_v[:, :max_index])
            # print(label)
            # print(prog_v)
            loss = criterion(out, label)
            print(loss)
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
        for j in range(bests):
            prog_v[j, max_index + label[j]] = 1
        max_index += i + 2
            

mean_result = []
best = [None, 100]

t = time()
for epoch in range(3):
    res = step()
    if res[0][1] < best[1]: best = res[0]
    mean_result.append(meanSecond(res))
    learn(res)
    print(epoch)
print(time() - t)

print(mean_result)
print(best)
nx.draw(from_edge_vec(best[0]))
plt.show()
```

Comment: I don't think it is correct to compute softmax over the first dimension (that is the batch dimension).

Comment: I actually found the problem, and you're right. In fact `nn.CrossEntropyLoss` compute a softmax so my program was computing softmax 2 times... Now it's working ! Ty very much :)